# XMLHttpRequest with JavaScript over Node.js issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found the following code online that is used to emulate the browser XMLHttpRequest object.

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

source: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest

But when I run the file file **text.js** which only has those 2 lines on node, I get the following error in the console:

```
Error: Cannot find the module 'xmlhttprequest'
```

**Question:** What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you install the package?

Comment: Have you [installed the module](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally) near your script / within your project?

Answer (score 0):

In your project directory, open a bash and type

```
 npm i xmlhttprequest
```